# How do I enable verbose as 'true' and access the LUIS recognizer result in Bot Composer?

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to retrieve top 5 intents from the LUIS recognizer result in Bot composer, but in my current implementation, `turn.recognized` does not give top 'n' intents. Instead it only gives the `topScoring` Intent. It seems like verbose is not enabled as true for the LUIS call. How can I enable verbose to be true and access the LUIS result in Bot Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following properties to prediction options of your `<botname>.en-us.lu.dialog`:

```
"predictionOptions": {
    "includeAPIResults": true,
    "includeAllIntents": true
    {
```